# can one give an android app permission it didn't ask for?

Tags: android, permissions, location, wifi, ssid

I believe this would make my old widget work on the new versions of the OS. Google has in its great wisdom changed the way permissions are dealt with, and the widget I'm fond of has stopped working...

This is about location permission to a widget that displays the SSID.

Possible?

Comment: Do you want to give location permission to user?

Comment: to an app. but maybe giving it to user would work as well.

Comment: Say what you want clearly please

Comment: i want to give an android app a permission it wasn't asking.

Comment: I don't understand what is the meaning of 'it wasn't asking'

Comment: android apps ask for permissions, in older versions of the OS at install, in never versions while they run. i want to grant a permission that the app did not ask for.

Comment: I gave your answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: so i need to find a way to uncompile / compile the apk? i'm an illiterate noob.

Comment: This is great question and I don't see many similar or any usable answer.
I'm using Total Commander on Android (without it i would not use Android) and I have wav recorder which stores files into unconventional place (not "media files" https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media). Then I want to convert wav to mp3 with FFmpeg but FFmpeg has only asked for "media files" permission and I would like to give it full access. I know it's all to protect me but it protects me from efficient way of living my life :D

Answer (score -1):

It depends to your permission. For some permissions you don't need to ask user to grant that permission to app. But for some of them you should get permission of user, otherwise you can't use that. Finding current location needs user to have permission to app. For example for location access you should add permission to your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
       ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: and how to give user a permission to the app?

Comment: I added to my answer